# Getting Values from javascript Ext.form.FormPanel and setting to variables

Tags: javascript, variables, formpanel

I have a problem with the following javascript:

```
var stereo_form =new Ext.form.FormPanel({
        id: "stereoInfo_panel",
        autoDestroy:true,
        frame: true,
        width: 410,
        items:[{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'DEM Resolution',
            name: 'resolution',
            value: '0.005' //sets a default value

        },{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Pyramid Level',
            name: 'matching',
            value: '0' //sets a default value

        },{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Size of DEM',
            name: 'size',
            value: '50.00' //sets a default value

        }],
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Confirm',
                handler: function()
                        {
                               // user1 = value of resolution field
                                                // user2 = value of matching field
                                                // user3 = value of size field
                            w.close();
                        }

        }]
    }); 

    var w =new Ext.Window({
        id: "stereoInfo_win",
        title: "Stereo Reconstruction Parameters",
        layout: 'form',
        height: 152,
        width: 415,
        items: stereo_form

    });
```

So I need the three user1, user2 and user3 variables to be assigned the values from the form fields resolution, matching and size when the 'confirm' button is pressed, how do I do this?

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var w = new Ext.Window({
        id: "stereoInfo_win",
        title: "Stereo Reconstruction Parameters",
        layout: 'form',
        height: 152,
        width: 415,
      items: {
        xtype: 'form',
        id: "stereoInfo_panel",
        frame: true,
        width: 410,
        items:[{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'DEM Resolution',
            name: 'resolution',
            value: '0.005' //sets a default value

        },{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Pyramid Level',
            name: 'matching',
            value: '0' //sets a default value

        },{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Size of DEM',
            name: 'size',
            value: '50.00' //sets a default value

        }],
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Confirm',
                handler: function(btn)
                 {

                 // console.log(Ext.getVersion()); // uncomment to know your extjs version

                 // traverse to the form object, then get the fields values
                 var values = btn.findParentByType('form').getForm().getValues();

                  user1 = values['resolution'];
                 user2 = values['matching'];
                 user3 = values['size'];

                 // traverse up again to the window object
                 btn.findParentByType('window').close();
             }

        }]
    }

});
```

Comment: Ok, this didn't work, and also now the window doesn't close..... I have coded:    buttons: [{
     text: 'Confirm',
     handler: function(btn)
       {
        var values = btn.up('stereo_form').getValues();
        Ext.Msg.alert('Attention', 'No Parameters entered by user');
        w.close();
       }
     
   }]
  }); 

  var w =new Ext.Window({
   id: "stereoInfo_win",
   title: "Stereo Reconstruction Parameters",
   layout: 'form',
   height: 152,
   width: 415,
   items: stereo_form
   
  });

Comment: None, just doesn't close window - doesn't assign variables a value and continues running the script in the background......

Comment: By the way, what version of ExtJS do you use?

Comment: I don't know! Inherited the script.... by the way what are the exact values I should be putting into 'form' and 'window' from looking at my script above?

Comment: I see. Those are aliases to those widgets. 'form' for Ext.form.FormPanel and 'window' for Ext.Window. Leave them as is.

Comment: Ok, done that and still no luck! Any ideas why the window isn't closing at least?

Comment: Have tried that new code, sadly same result, window doesn't close and the variables do not change.....

Comment: You are probably using version <= 3.4. Try again.